# Identifying a bad advisor (before applying)

Tags: advisor, application

Earlier this year, I contacted this Professor (Applied Math) from a top Canadian university and we talked twice this year. He earned his PhD from an Ivy League school and must be around 60 years old. He seems to be a really nice guy, happy to have me as his student, and the university is in a city that I like a lot. However, there is something that concerns me.

He has only had four students over more than 20 years. Three of them stayed in academia in American universities, but only one of them (the youngest) is actively engaged in research in a tier 3 university (the other two are lecturers in tier 2 universities). His other student got a post-doc in a top university in the US, but returned to his home country afterwards (a developing one).

Are my concerns justified?

Comment: Hard to tell. Maybe, not necessarily. I'd suggest a polite e-mail to the youngest ex-student to ask how their experience with the professor was.

Comment: Excepting UofT and UBC, these are roughly average outcomes for a PhD in math from one of the better Canadian universities.  (For UofT and UBC, this set of outcomes is well within the range of possibilities given the sample size.)

Comment: I don't think you can really judge whether a Prof is bad based solely on his/her past students who completed their degree.  First, in your example, all his/her students graduated; a good sign.  Second, he/she may not have many students due to funding or his/her areas of interest.  Third, he/she may be very picky.   Fourth, where his/her students ended up may be due to personal reasons.  Having said that, I would worry more about personality clashes.  Also, you do not see the number of students who have quit; this is probably a better indicator but it not public knowledge.

Comment: I agree with @AlexanderWoo that those job outcomes are actually reasonably strong.  Four students is a little on the low end, but it's not unusual for people to wait for tenure to start advising and then only advise one student at a time, so it's not unreasonably few students.

Comment: Could you say what the problem with those outcomes are? Isn't it good if somebody helps their developing country? Isn't it good if people go where they want to go (presumably) instead of going to the best universities?

Answer (score 3):

I do not know whether the low number of former PhD students per se is a good sign or bad. A high number of dropouts and former students consistently ending up at very mediocre jobs in academia would definitely be a ground for concern. In what follows, I address a slightly broader question.

You might find it helpful to change your perspective from the good/bad dimension to something like suitable/unsuitable for you personally.

Looking at your potential advisor's CV, you may ask yourself if they seem to be successful due to their original high-quality research or thanks to their soft skills and social initiative? Do they hold posts of authority within the university or as editors and conference organisers? Do they appear to follow their own research strategy or do they tend to jump on the bandwagon from time to time? Do they apply one method to many problems or work on one problem using many methods? Do they take a student to start working on a new challenging problem together or do all their students travel essentially the same path (presumably being spoon-fed in the process)?

By looking at their recent or current students' CVs, you can see what sort of opportunities they were able to take advantage of. Publications, conference presentations - how many and how good? Summer school attendance, teaching (in what capacity: TA or tutor), helping to organise events and public outreach - chores for some, but joy for others - do you want this? Did the student get a chance to visit other groups/labs during their PhD? Did they co-author with various people from other places? Did they publish a couple of papers as the first and corresponding author or did they exchange their technical skills (i.e., coding) for a few middle-author publications?

One can often find the first-hand account of the PhD life in the Acknowledgement section of a thesis/dissertation. Some people share a lot of personal information there. It is worth checking out, especially if you are considering politely contacting a former student, as someone suggested.

While the above guesses and extrapolations can be unreliable and even unwarranted, I find them more useful than merely checking how many of former PhD students got employed and where.

Answer (score 2):

There is probably no issue here and the careers of his students are determined primarily by their actions, not his. It might be a function of the popularity of the subfield in which they work.

But if the professor is listed in the [Mathematics Genealogy Project](https://genealogy.math.ndsu.nodak.edu) you can find the titles of the dissertations of the students and check for yourself whether their work was significant as students. You can also find out whether they "produced" any mathematical heirs.

Comment: "and" -> "any" in last sentence (too small for me to edit)

Comment: @BenBolker, fixed. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to identify a good advisor before applying for a PhD position is to examine the professor's publication record.  You can examine a lot of professors' publication records quickly.  Detailed investigation of how that professor relates to their students can wait until you have an offer.  It's a more labor intensive process where you should contact previous students and ask them for advice.

You should be very concerned if a professor with a long career has only placed one student into industry employment.  This might indicate a professor who does not understand the realities of the job market.  The vast majority of PhD students will not work in academia, and those that work outside academia will be paid more.

If you are seeking a career in academia, then a 75% placement rate into low ranked academic jobs is a very good record.

Comment: This might make sense in areas of engineering and biomedicine that are relevant to industry, but it's nonsense in the humanities (including pure math) where, with a very few very specific exceptions, people who go into industry end up in the kind of job I had *before* grad school where a PhD is irrelevant (though it can make up for an undistinguished BA).

Comment: @AlexanderWoo The fact that some industry jobs don't require a PhD does not imply a good advisor will not help a student prepare for such an industry job.  Which part are you claiming is "nonsense"?

Comment: What preparation is there to do?  The student is already prepared for the job.  I consistently advise someone who wants such a job to start looking for one and leave the PhD as soon as they get it - because they might as well make more money now.  In fact, if you are taking an industry job, it's better to NOT graduate even if you have finished a dissertation.  The industry job won't care if you've graduated, and in case you change your mind and want to go back into academia, a more recent degree makes you more competitive.